# Twig extends within an extends?

Tags: twig

I have a twig `fileA` using the extends on twig `fileB`. Can a new `fileC` use extends on `fileA`?

The [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html) says the following but im not sure if its saying this isnt possible or not:

> Like PHP, Twig does not support multiple inheritance. So you can only have one extends tag called per rendering. However, Twig supports horizontal reuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, definitely. This is also possible in php:

```
class fileA extends fileB {}

class fileC extends fileA {}
```

You just cannot extend multiple files at once.